# Compare contrasts in linear model in Python (like Rs contrast library?)

Tags: linear-regression, statsmodels

In R I can do the following to compare two contrasts from a linear model:

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/spider_wolff_gorb_2013.csv"
filename <- "spider_wolff_gorb_2013.csv"
install.packages("downloader", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(downloader)
if (!file.exists(filename)) download(url, filename)
spider <- read.csv(filename, skip=1)
head(spider, 5)
#   leg type friction
# 1  L1 pull     0.90
# 2  L1 pull     0.91
# 3  L1 pull     0.86
# 4  L1 pull     0.85
# 5  L1 pull     0.80
fit = lm(friction ~ type + leg, data=spider)
fit
# Call:
# lm(formula = friction ~ type + leg, data = spider)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)     typepush        legL2        legL3        legL4
#      1.0539      -0.7790       0.1719       0.1605       0.2813
install.packages("contrast", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
library(contrast)
l4vsl2 = contrast(fit, list(leg="L4", type="pull"), list(leg="L2",type="pull"))
l4vsl2
# lm model parameter contrast
# 
#   Contrast       S.E.      Lower     Upper    t  df Pr(>|t|)
#  0.1094167 0.04462392 0.02157158 0.1972618 2.45 277   0.0148
```

I have found out how to do much of the above in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/spider_wolff_gorb_2013.csv", sep=",", skiprows=1)
df.head(2)

import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

model1 = sm.ols(formula='friction ~ type + leg', data=df)
fitted1 = model1.fit()
print(fitted1.summary())
```

Now all that remains is finding the t-statistic for the contrast of leg pair L4 vs. leg pair L2. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question with a complete, executable example and the reference code and numbers. That makes it much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

statsmodels is still missing some predefined contrasts, but the `t_test` and `wald_test` or `f_test` methods of the model Results classes can be used to test linear (or affine) restrictions. The restrictions either be given by arrays or by strings using the parameter names.

Details for how to specify contrasts/restrictions should be in the documentation

for example

```
>>> tt = fitted1.t_test("leg[T.L4] - leg[T.L2]")
>>> print(tt.summary())
                             Test for Constraints                             
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c0             0.1094      0.045      2.452      0.015       0.022       0.197
==============================================================================
```

The results are attributes or methods in the instance that is returned by t_test. For example the conf_int can be obtained by

```
>>> tt.conf_int()
array([[ 0.02157158,  0.19726175]])
```

`t_test` is vectorized and treats each restriction or contrast as separate hypothesis. `wald_test` treats a list of restrictions as joint hypothesis:

```
>>> tt = fitted1.t_test(["leg[T.L3] - leg[T.L2], leg[T.L4] - leg[T.L2]"])
>>> print(tt.summary())
                             Test for Constraints                             
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c0            -0.0114      0.043     -0.265      0.792      -0.096       0.074
c1             0.1094      0.045      2.452      0.015       0.022       0.197
==============================================================================


>>> tt = fitted1.wald_test(["leg[T.L3] - leg[T.L2], leg[T.L4] - leg[T.L2]"])
>>> print(tt.summary())
<F test: F=array([[ 8.10128575]]), p=0.00038081249480917173, df_denom=277, df_num=2>
```

Aside: this also works for robust covariance matrices if `cov_type` was specified as argument to `fit`.

Comment: Thanks. This might be in the documentation, but I was too ignorant to find it (I am currently learning the theory.)